# What is the keyboard shortcut opposite to Ctrl+k?

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> deletes rest of line in an UNIX command line. How do I delete all the text *before* the cursor?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>:

From `bash` documentation, [Killing And Yanking](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Commands-For-Killing):

> unix-line-discard (C-u)
>
> Kill backward from the cursor to the beginning of the current line.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> behavior is not only controlled by the shells that have their own line editor like `bash`, `zsh`, `tcsh`, `sh -o emacs`, but also by the line discipline  of the terminal driver when in canonical mode (like in `cat`, or basic implementations of `sh`/`ksh` when no line-editor is enabled). Thus it works everywhere.

You can check line discipline  of the terminal driver using `stty -a` (or `stty -everything` in BSD system):

```
$ stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 24; columns 80; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = M-^?; eol2 = M-^?;
swtch = M-^?; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W;
lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff
-iuclc ixany imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke
```

Comment: "It only works if your shell supports Readline Emacs Editing Mode". This is false. `^u` is managed by the TTY line discipline (as long as the TTY is in line input mode, as opposed to character input mode). Thus it works everywhere. See `man stty` and look for `kill CHAR`. Also, I keep my shell in vi-mode, and it works there too.

Comment: @Patrick: Don't know about this, remove that wrong part.

Comment: @Patrick, No. `^U`, kills the whole input buffer when the terminal is in canonical mode. `bash` doesn't put the terminal in canonical mode at its prompt. It handles the input and output by itself. ^U kills the whole line in zsh, the whole input buffer in tcsh, ksh88, ksh93, mksh, pdksh, libedit (dash, other shells linked to libedit), from the cursor to the beginning of the buffer in readline (`bash` and other shells linked to readline). For the line discipline's internal editor, ^U erases the whole input, which the same as from the cursor to the beginning of the buffer as you can't move the cu

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: So, the `^U` behaviour is controlled by the terminal or the shell?

Comment: By the shell for shells that have their own line editor (`bash`, `zsh`, `tcsh`, `sh -o emacs`), but the line discipline of the terminal _driver_ in when in canonical mode (like in `cat`, or basic implementations of `sh`/`ksh` when no line-editor is enabled). The terminal driver internal line editor has not support for ^K or moving the cursor.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Thanks for the information, updated my answer.

Comment: Note that as I said, `^U` kills to the beginning of the line _only in readline/bash_, not in other shells.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: In `bash`, `^K` also kills to the end of the buffer, so I think `^U` is the reverse of it?

Comment: Indeed, sorry. Note that `^K` is `kill-line` so it's a bit misleading. Note that there's also a `backward-kill-line` bound on `^X^?` (that also kills more than one line).